# Failed to deploy flask with uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker: images 404 (Not Found)

Tags: python, image, docker, flask, http-status-code-404

I am deploying a simple flask app on ubuntu 14 server based on Docker: [uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask). Images are ok in local machine, but there are 404 Not Found for images.

(1) directory structure

I have a directory structure like example-flask-package-python3.7.zip, which is provided by [uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask).

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── main1.py
│   │   ├── main.py
│   │   ├── model
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   └── images
│   │   │        ├── logo_python2.jpg
│   │   │        └── logo_python.png
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── hi.html
│   │   │   └── upload.html
│   │   └── upload
│   └── uwsgi.ini
├── Dockerfile
```

(2) main.py

```py
from flask import Flask,render_template, request, url_for, send_from_directory,jsonify, redirect
app = Flask(name)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('hi.html')
if name == "main":
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=80)
```

(3) hi.html

In the hi.thml, in addition to html, head, body, I simplily insert two images. the code to give the src of images are as follows:

```
src="./static/images/logo_python.png"
src="{{url_for('static',filename='images/logo_python2.jpg')}}"
```

The images are shown in my pc, but it doesn't work when I deployed the app in the remote ubuntu server. 
"404 Not Found" ----It looks like the web server cannot find the two images.

Please anyone can help me to solve it? Thanks in advance.